# Chrome Icon in Extensions Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension has an icon declared in the manifest which shows up perfectly in the icon tray in the top right of chrome.  It is declared as follows:

```
"icons": { 
        "1": "images/icon.png"
        },
```

However, I still get the "gear" icon both when (1) I install the program and (2) in the chrome extension page.

What am I missing from the manifest to correctly set the image at images/icon.png to be displayed in those two places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `16`, `48` and `128` as properties of object corresponding to image `width`, from `16` to `128`. `1` would specify an image with `width` of `1px`

```
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" }
```

Comment: I know.  But I thought there would be no reason to do that if I only wanted a single image.  Does this solve the problem I described?